# Kendo line chart - gap between points

Tags: kendo-ui, linechart

I am using the latest version of Kendo charts and I would like a line chart that has a gap between years - each year has 3 vertical-axis points.

What I have tried

- I cannot use the missingSpace 'gap' property because the values where the gap will appear won't necessarily be null.
- I cannot use different data sources for each year because I need the hover-over and click functionality in the legend to result hide/show/disable of the corresponding line over all years.  Using different data sources makes each legend entry associate to only one part (i.e. one year) of the line
- I thought I could make the color of the line "transparent" so I used the method described http://jsfiddle.net/whoamiwho/EE22M/ but it only changes the color of the points (not the lines connecting the points) - below is the code in the jsfiddle

```
    $("#chart").kendoChart({ series: [{
        colorField: "valueColor",
        data: [
         { value: 1, valueColor: "red" },
         { value: 2, valueColor: "green" },
         { value: 2, valueColor: "blue" }
        ]
      }],
      seriesDefaults: {
        type: "line",
        markers: {
           // background: "#da7633",
        },
        style: "smooth",
        missingValues: "gap" 
        //width: "3px"
      },
    });
```

- I thought I could make the width of the line zero (0) using a similar approach to the link above however although the color can be changed (via delegating to a function) the width of the line cannot be changed in the same way as you cannot define a function against the width property

Can anyone help ?

Comment: "I cannot use the missingSpace 'gap' property because the values where the gap will appear won't necessarily be null" What is the login applied here? The gap property is working as it should on your example. The only way to have different line colors will be stacking as described here https://www.telerik.com/forums/line-chart-single-line-multi-color like this http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/eruJE

Comment: Perhaps I'm not understanding you correctly - what is being asked in the post/link you provide is what I'm after (i.e. see the clarification reply by the person who authored the original post that mentions "just to make my question more clear ... what I'm looking for is to have the line from 5 to 1 red, 1 to 18 blue, 18 to 3 white, 3 to 15 green etc").  However I *don't* see that the answer to that clarification actually fulfills that requirement.  The post is asking for different colors between points on the *same* line - it is *not* asking for different lines with different colors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I found the approach of separate data sources (one that shows up in the legend, the rest hidden) was the best way to achieve this as per https://dojo.telerik.com/ILIYofED/18 - note the click/mouseover events allow the entire line (which actually contains separate data sources) to look like it behaves as one

```
...
series: [
  {
    field: "value",
    categoryField: "year",
    name: "United States",
    color: "orange"
  },
  {
    field: "expectedValue",
    dashType: "dash",
    color: "orange",
    name: "auxilliary",
    visibleInLegend: false

  }
],
legendItemClick: function(e){
  var chart = this;
  if(e.series.name === "United States"){
    chart.findSeriesByName("auxilliary").toggleVisibility(!e.series.visible);
  }
},
legendItemHover: function(e){
  var chart = this;
  if(e.series.name === "United States"){
    chart.findSeriesByName("auxilliary").toggleHighlight(e.series.highlight.visible);
  }
},          
legendItemLeave: function(e){
  var chart = this;
  if(e.series.name === "United States"){
    chart.findSeriesByName("auxilliary").toggleHighlight(!e.series.highlight.visible);
  }
}, 
...
```